# folder structure for python with pydev, unit tests, etc

Tags: python, pypi, python-unittest

I'm a little confused as to the recommended way to set things up. I'm using PyDev/Eclipse and just starting out.

I tried to set up unit tests and read many stackoverflow articles on accessing unit tests from different folders. Coming from a java background none seemed very pretty.

So I ended up with two sibling folders/packages for my code:

```
project\
    src\
        mainpackage\
            __init__.py
            maincode.py

        mainpackage-test\
            __init__.py
            tests.py
```

and in my tests.py added 'sys.path.import("../") which made things work.

But then I read a link to a 'standard' newsgroup response:
http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html

Which says don't create a src folder and do put tests in sub-packages

So I did this:

```
project\
    src\
        mainpackage\
            __init__.py
            maincode.py

            mainpackage-test\
                __init__.py
                tests.py
```

1. Why does pydev want a 'src' if the recommended approach is not to?
2. Which of the above two folder structures is better in terms of ease of use and testing within and outside of eclipse or with other tools such as nose?
3. I can't find reference to where to put the other 'standard' package files and folders such as setup.py, bin, docs, etc. Do I put them within src, which doesn't make sense to me or outside of src at the same level but will it have issues with package systems like pypi, etc.

Comment: Don't use a `src` directory at all. http://bit.ly/pypackages has good tips on organization of a project.

Comment: Storing modules in `src` is currently one of the projects layouts officially recommended by setuptools.  See [setuptool's article on Package Discovery and Namespace Package](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html).  Disregard the previous comment by @Wooble as it's terribly outdated.